# Find an empty cell and write something in another column in a huge file

Tags: vba, excel

I have huge files (over 500,000 rows) and I need to find if the "M" column is equal to "", if it is equal to "", than I need to write down something in the "N" column.

I do it with = to "" because `IsEmpty()` isn't working in those files (not sure why).

This is my current code: (I removed what wasn't necessary)

```
Sub sbVBA_COMMENTS_ExcelSheets()

'CONSTANTS SERVICENTRE FILES (PROD FOUR)
Const SC_STRLINE As Integer = 4 'FIRST PART IS ALWAYS AT LINE 4
Const SC_COLNUM As String = "B" 'PART NUMBERS WILL ALWAYS BE IN THE B COLUM FOR EVERY EXCEL FILES
Const SC_COLMKT As String = "K" 'NEW MARKETING CODE WILL ALWAYS BE IN THE K COLUM FOR EVERY EXCEL FILES
Const SC_COLDCT As String = "M" 'NEW DISCOUNT CODE WILL ALWAYS BE IN THE M COLUM FOR EVERY EXCEL FILES
Const SC_COLPRB As String = "N" 'NEW COMMENTS AND PROBLEM CODE WILL ALWAYS BE IN THE M COLUM FOR EVERY EXCEL FILES

'VARIABLES
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ct As Long

'SET VARIABLES
RowCount = 0
ct = SC_STRLINE

Sheets(4).Select

'ADD COMMENTS
With Sheets(4)
    RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

While ct <= RowCount

    If Sheets(4).Range(SC_COLDCT & ct).Value = "" Then

        Sheets(4).Range(SC_COLPRB & ct).Value = "EMPTY"

    End If

    ct = ct + 1

Wend

'FILTER BY COMMENTS
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range(SC_COLPRB & (SC_STRLINE - 1)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PROD FOUR").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

This is working... somehow... but it's SUPER SLOW and when I run the macro, my Excel dies almost 70% of the time.

Also sometimes, this macro will cause a problem where it will write down EMPTY everywhere for some reason...

Basically, i'm looking for a faster and cleaner way to do the same thing.

Is there a way to gain performance while doing the same thing?

Note that I'm not a coder, so if you could answer me in a way I can understand, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `.Value2` instead of `.Value`

Comment: Are you using `Application.ScreenUpdating = Fals`e, `Application.Calculation = xlManual`, etc.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below code. Instead of dealing with a range, this converts the range into an array which will hopefully be faster.

```
Sub sbVBA_COMMENTS_ExcelSheets()

'CONSTANTS SERVICENTRE FILES (PROD FOUR)
Const SC_STRLINE As Integer = 4 'FIRST PART IS ALWAYS AT LINE 4
Const SC_COLNUM As String = "B" 'PART NUMBERS WILL ALWAYS BE IN THE B COLUM FOR EVERY EXCEL FILES
Const SC_COLMKT As String = "K" 'NEW MARKETING CODE WILL ALWAYS BE IN THE K COLUM FOR EVERY EXCEL FILES
Const SC_COLDCT As String = "M" 'NEW DISCOUNT CODE WILL ALWAYS BE IN THE M COLUM FOR EVERY EXCEL FILES
Const SC_COLPRB As String = "N" 'NEW COMMENTS AND PROBLEM CODE WILL ALWAYS BE IN THE M COLUM FOR EVERY EXCEL FILES

'VARIABLES
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim varray As Variant
Dim i As Long

'SET VARIABLES
RowCount = 0
ct = SC_STRLINE

'disable unnecessary hindrances 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)

'find last row
RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

varray = Range(SC_COLDCT & SC_STRLINE & ":" & SC_COLDCT & RowCount).Value

For i = UBound(varray, 1) To LBound(varray, 1) Step -1
    If varray(i, 1) = "" Then 'if nothing
       .Range(SC_COLPRB & i + 4).Value = "EMPTY"
    End If
Next


'FILTER BY COMMENTS
.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range(SC_COLPRB & (SC_STRLINE - 1)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal

End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PROD FOUR").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand how this works. Should I put ct = ct+1 just before Next?

When will it stop with for?

Comment: Since dealing with arrays is much fast then dealing with ranges, I converted the values in the range to the values in an array. The for loop iterates through each element of the array (aka each cell value) and checks the condition if nothing then populate the column N with "EMPTY"

Comment: Ok I've tried it, it's wayyyy faster... thank you! I also see that you updated your code to fix the "ct" problem. Perfect man! thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

The simple code below accomplishes what you want quickly. You can also use "" instead of vbNullString.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lR As Long

lR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lR
        If Cells(i, "M").Value = vbNullString Then
           Cells(i, "N").Value = "Empty"
        End If
    Next i
```